# Liferay - Custom permission - NoSuchRessourceActionException

Tags: security, service, liferay, action

I implemented my own service builder extension with custom services and custom access permissions to the common section of the user admin portlet.

Until yesterday everything worked fine. The custom actions where shown and I could grant within the role system.

Now, since I made smaller changes for e.g. renaming actions to my default.xml file I got the following Exception:

```
javax.portlet.PortletException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.NoSuchResourceActionException: 90#REMOVE_ROLE
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:202)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:392)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:93)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:249)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:105) ...
```

This happens now on every custom action. I tried to reinstall the extension and also to restart the server itself but no change to that behavior.

I cannot select anymore my own custom actions.

My default.xml file looks like

```
<resource-action-mapping>
<portlet-resource>
    <portlet-name>90</portlet-name>
    <permissions>
        <supports>
            <action-key>REMOVE_ROLE</action-key>
            <action-key>REMOVE_USER_GROUP</action-key>
            <action-key>REMOVE_ORGANIZATION</action-key>
            <action-key>ADD_SITE_MEMBER</action-key>
            <action-key>REMOVE_SITE_MEMBER</action-key>
        </supports>
        <site-member-defaults>
        </site-member-defaults>
        <guest-defaults>
        </guest-defaults>
        <guest-unsupported>
            <action-key>REMOVE_ROLE</action-key>
            <action-key>REMOVE_USER_GROUP</action-key>
            <action-key>REMOVE_ORGANIZATION</action-key>
            <action-key>ADD_SITE_MEMBER</action-key>
            <action-key>REMOVE_SITE_MEMBER</action-key>
        </guest-unsupported>
    </permissions>
</portlet-resource> 
...
```

My *Language.properties* file is also adapted and looks like

```
... 
action.REMOVE_MEMBERS=Remove members
action.REMOVE_ROLE=Remove role
action.REMOVE_USER_GROUP=Remove user group
action.REMOVE_ORGANIZATION=Remove organization
action.ADD_SITE_MEMBER=Add member to site
action.REMOVE_SITE_MEMBER=Remove member from site 
...
```

Does have anyone an idea what is missing and why the same approach worked yesterday while today an exception is thrown?

I tried anything to solve this problem also clearing the cache but the error remains no matter what I do.

Comment: Are you pointing to the right XML file int the portlet.properties file? Could you post it?

Comment: Hi Miroslav, yes the configuration is ok. Moreover yesterday I started the application again and now it works. It looks to me like a caching problem. I face the same problem when I do hot deployments of my developments. For any reason it looks like that default.xml is not correctly processed or something remains in the cache.